# What is all the browser agent stuff?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, browser, user-agent

I am new to ASP.NET and wanted to capture details about people on my site. So I capture the `Request.UserAgent` attributes to file. Can anyone explain how to deconstruct these so I know what they mean? I am actually stumped by some of the user agents I see. Examples:

- `IE2.0d; WinNT: Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 2.0d; Windows NT)`: Never heard of IE2.0, so is this spoofed for scanning my site, and why? Also, how is IE related to Mozilla in this case?
- `IE6.0; WinXP: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; YPC 3.0.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; yplus 4.4.02b)`: People seriously use IE6.0 these days?? And what is all the rest of that stuff, like YPC and yplus?
- `Mozilla0.0; Win2000: Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Windows NT 5.0; U)`: Hmmm... That's a weird Mozilla version?

Comment: Doesn't your hosting provider offer some sort of basic statistics information based on the raw access logs? Such information would include details about browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this website will be very helpful to you:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

You can copy and paste user agents into this index page and have it do a simple analysis.
http://www.useragentstring.com/index.php

Answer (score 2):

A user agent is used to identify the application that accessed a specific web site or service.

The common pattern:

***Mozilla/[version] ([system and browser information]) [platform] ([platform details]) [extensions]***

Source for this information: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

Since the user agent is exposed by a commonly accessible string, this can be modified easily (aka spoofed) - a method that can be easily done in .NET by directly modifying the UserAgent property - that way you can, for example, identify your download manager as Internet Explorer while it doesn't have anything to do with it. Not saying it's a good practice since it messes with visit stats, but you need this from time to time - for example, to access a web stream from a website that is only accessible through an app and not through a web browser. All you need is to know the user agent for that app and then pass it inside your own application.

A pretty decent source of information for your case would be [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In case you are wondering why IE is sometimes identified as Mozilla, here is what Microsoft has to say in their official docs:

> For historical reasons, Internet
>   Explorer identifies itself as a
>   Mozilla 4.0 browser.

Comment: For anyone interested you can read an informative article about the historical reasons as to why IE identifies itself as a Mozilla 4.0 browser here: http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/