# what is use of "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0" string in curl

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is all the browser agent stuff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847072/what-is-all-the-browser-agent-stuff)

What is use of `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0` string in curl? What is meaning of `windows; u; windows NT 5.1; en-US; ry:1.8.1` and why is this string in used in curl with `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`?

Answer (score 1):

Its not cURL, its HTTP, that allows a header [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent), that describes the user agent of the client.